# Is there any good back-end independent HTML/CSS/JS widget for many-to-many/has_many relations with XHR filtering?

Tags: javascript, html, css, has-and-belongs-to-many, m2m

I've been looking around for a good back-end independent HTML/CSS/JS widget for many-to-many/has_many relations with XHR filtering and I can't seem to find any.

I find hard to believe people are constantly re-inventing this wheel.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: Ok, from the number of people that didn't understand it, this was a crappy question.

I believe that regular web interactions should come at minimal cost (it should either already be in HTML or a package install away).

That's true for most cases. However, I'm having a hard time finding something for picking up an item from a collection (Not autocomplete, something more elaborate than merely a string. If you want an example, assume you want to pick users and have their avatar displayed while picking.).

Picture this:

When you want the user to provide

- a short string in a form, you give them an input box
- a long text in a form, you give them a text area
- a piece of HTML (for a blog post's body, for example), you give them a text area with [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)
- pick something from a short list, you give them a drop down menu (like a select box)
- a string based on a wide range of known alternatives, you give them an input box with autocomplete ([jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), [YUI Autocomplete](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/autocomplete/), etc..)
- a set of items from a wide range of options, you give them... *drumroll...*

I don't know! And that's my question. I've searched a bit and could only come up with [jquery-tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html) as a credible option.

Comment: you're being unclear, what's the widget's purpose?

Comment: I assure you I personally am not reinventing a wheel that could be described like that. At least, I really hope not.

Comment: @EliranMalka Can I be more clear than many-to-many/has_many relations? For example, Actor habtm Skill. I want a decent widget for that. And don't say checkbox list. :P

Comment: well, you can be more vague, obviously. please describe: **1.** the specific data / data-structure to be displayed. **2.** the desired GUI or look and feel expected by the user. thanks.

Comment: @EliranMalka Data: Anything that can be represented in HTML. Yes, that vague. I'm looking for something really generic. UI: Something like this: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html

Comment: I would also point out Django's default widget for m2m's but it's to restrictive in presentation (can't put the avatars in a user list, for example).